# Terraform Destroy will not destroy my HashiCorp Vault internal groups

Tags: terraform, identity, hashicorp-vault

I have provisioned a number of HashiCorp Vault resources including internal and external Identity Groups, using Terraform. All resources are successfully captured in my local state file.

However, I've noticed that when I run the `terraform destroy` command expecting all of my Vault resources to be deleted, the command fails to act on my Vault Identity Groups and they remain untouched.

Is this a known bug with Terraform or Vault, or am I missing something?

Comment: Care to add some code you have to the question? Maybe there are some `lifecycle` settings somewhere that prevent it from being destroyed?

Comment: @MarkoE thanks for the input. Any particular code you want shared? My scenario is fairly simple in all honesty. I am just executing the basic command - terraform destroy --auto-approve. Nothing else aside this, which I expect to then destroy the resources provisioned through my terraform configuration, all of which are captured in my local state file.

Comment: Ideally everything except the state file would be good, taking care to obfuscate anything sensitive of course.